# How to print from A word to B word?( awk )

Tags: regex, awk

I need to print from the word 'update' to ';'.

*file.txt:*

```
-- Host (first) kkk (queen1)
-- prince princess#/king 1/1
update schema.table_name t set "A=123","B=234" where "C=222" and "D=333"
and "F=2342";

-- Host (first) ddd (queen2)
-- prince princess#/king 2/2
update schema2.table_name2 t set "A=123","B=234" where "C=222" and "D=333"
and "F=2342";
```

With the below awk, I can specify the block to parse, but I'm not sure how I can print the statement from update....until semicolon().

*file.awk:*

```
BEGIN {
}
/-- Host/,/;/ {                          
   if (/-- Host/) printf "%s#%s#",$3,$5; 
   if (/update /) printf ??????????????; 
}
END {
}
```

This is how I execute it:

```
awk -f file.awk -F'[ ()]+' file.txt
```

Can you let me know of any idea?

Comment: Just a hint, you can omit the empty `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is, the `update...` line was broken into multiple lines. This one-liner may help you. However you perhaps have to adjust it a little bit to fit your whole script.

```
awk 'p||/^update/{p=1;printf "%s",$0}/;$/&&p{p=0;print ""}' file
```

with your file as input, it outputs:

```
update schema.table_name t set "A=123","B=234" where "C=222" and "D=333"and "F=2342";
update schema2.table_name2 t set "A=123","B=234" where "C=222" and "D=333"and "F=2342";
```

Comment: I need to keep the indentation of the statement. I just need to print the original SQL statement. Thank you.

Comment: ## Awk script ( file.awk ) :  tried but failed to print the statement.

    /] /,/;/ {        
                  if (/-- Host/) printf "%s#%s#",$3,$5; 
        else if (/update:$/) {
            splitHipen=$2;
                             split(splitHipen,splitHipenArr,".");
              printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[1],2,length(splitHipenArr[1])-2);   #TABLE_OWNER
                       printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[2],2,length(splitHipenArr[2])-2);   #TABLE_NAME
        
                 { matched = 1; } 
        if matched { print; }
        
        }
        
       }

Comment: @Sigularity my line gave you the idea how to handle the case, you need adjust it to put in your script.  If you want to keep the line breaks, use print, not printf. do some test.

Comment: It was really helpful to make my script look better. Now it works !! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

awk idiomatic way of doing this is

```
awk '/update/,/;/' file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. Can I use that way in IF statement like IF ( /update/,/;/ )? when I tried it, it failed. I need to print all of contents from UPDATE to the semicolon.

Comment: Just try the script as is. You don't need an if statement.

Comment: @karakfa range pattern will fail if `update` and `;` in one line.